# rescue Timeouts with SystemTimer

Tags: ruby, timeout

I'm using the SystemTimer gem to deal with timeout problems.
https://github.com/ph7/system-timer

I can't find a way to catch the Exception when a Timeout

```
begin
  SystemTimer.timeout_after(10.seconds) do
    # facebook api
    rest_graph.fql(query)
  end
rescue RestGraph::Error::InvalidAccessToken
  return nil
rescue Timeout::Error
  # never executed
end
```

But the last Exception Timeout::Error is never triggered.

Comment: [12:19][~]$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [Timeout](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/timeout/1.9.2/frames), which comes with 1.9.2 and is designed to do this?

```
require 'timeout'
status = Timeout::timeout(5) {
  # Something that should be interrupted if it takes too much time...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (based on your link)

```
class TimedOut < StandardError
end

begin
  SystemTimer.timeout_after(10.seconds, TimedOut) do
    # ...
  end
rescue TimedOut
  # ...
end
```